The fastest solution for $\int \sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx$
The integral $(1)$ is typically attacked using trigonometric substitution, more specifically, using Case II, which involves substituting $x=a\tan{\theta}$. This method leads to having to evaluate the integral of secant cubed, which can be solved either by integration by parts or using the reduction formula. Here we provide an alternative approach to solve the integral $(1)$ and the like.
Let's evaluate the integral
$$\int\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx\tag{1}$$
We will make use of the following general transformation formula:

$$\int f\left(x, \sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right)\, dx = \int f\left(\frac{e^{\theta}-e^{-\theta}}{2}a, \frac{e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}}{2}a\right) \frac{e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}}{2}a\, d\theta\tag{2}$$

Where $\theta=\sinh^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})$ and $a>0$.
Solution. From $(2)$ follows that
$$\begin{aligned}\int\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx&=\frac14\int \left(e^\theta+e^{-\theta}\right)^2\, d\theta\\&=\frac14\int \left(e^{2\theta}+e^{-2\theta}+2\right)\,d\theta\\&=\frac{e^{2\theta}-e^{-2\theta}}{8}+\frac{\theta}{2}+C\\&=\frac{e^{2\sinh^{-1}(x)}-e^{-2\sinh^{-1}(x)}}{8}+\frac{\sinh^{-1}(x)}{2}+C \end{aligned}$$
Compare this solution with the one provided in the Blackpenredpen and Integrals for you channels. The closed forms can be proven equivalent to the one given here easily. Now, I consider that the solutions provided through these YouTube channels are much more complicated than the general solution I am proposing here for this type of integrals. Do you know of a simpler solution than mine? I don't consider the substitution $x=\sinh(u)$ to be simpler than this, as suggested by the number of questions in this forum asking for solutions that don't use trigonometric or hyperbolic substitutions.
This solution is part of a much more general method that can be seen as an alternative to trigonometric substitution (although it does more than that). You can go to the section 'An alternative method to trigonometric substitution' on my blog and refer to Example 5 for further illustration. For other cases you also have
$$\int f\left(x,\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}, \tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}} \right)\,dx=\int f\left(\frac{e^{i\alpha}+e^{-i\alpha}}{2}a, e^{i\alpha}, \frac{1-e^{i\alpha}}{1+e^{i\alpha}}\right)\,\frac{e^{-i\alpha}-e^{i\alpha}}{2i}a\,d\alpha\tag{3}$$
$$\int f\left(x, \sqrt{x^2-a^2}, \frac{\sqrt{x-a}}{\sqrt{x+a}}\right)\,dx= \int f\left(\frac{e^{i\alpha}+e^{-i\alpha}}{2}a, \frac{e^{-i\alpha}-e^{i\alpha}}{2}a, \frac{1-e^{i\alpha}}{1+e^{i\alpha}}\right)\,\frac{e^{-i\alpha}-e^{i\alpha}}{2i}a\,d\alpha\tag{4}$$
Where $\alpha=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$, $\beta=\csc^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$, $\gamma=\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$ and $\frac{x}{a}\geq1$.
Apart from the Euler substitutions, do you know of any other general approaches that allow getting rid of trigonometric or hyperbolic substitutions (which can be quite bothersome for students) that you could share? Thanks in advance.

Why not just make the substitution $x=\sinh u$ and do the simple integral of $\cosh^2u$ without your trickery?

@TedShifrin: I overlooked that substitution. However, many students prefer approaches that avoid trigonometric or hyperbolic substitutions. I have edited my question.

The substitution you have done is exactly a hyperbolic substitution but the hyperbolic is in its expanded form.

The hyperbolic functions are implicit in transformation $(2)$. However, what transformation $(2)$ and the other transformations allow is to bring you into the realm of exponential functions (there aren't as many integration formulas here compared to trigonometric functions, so you don't have to memorize as much).

Transformations $(2, 3, 4)$ allow you to convert rational integrals of trigonometric/hyperbolic functions into integrals of rational functions immediately. Then you can apply partial fraction decomposition. I reiterate, the common complaint from students is that they need to memorize too much for trigonometric/hyperbolic substitutions or rely on tables. The transformations I provide avoid that.

Another possible approach based on the integration by parts method:
\begin{align*}
\int\sqrt{x^{2} + 1}\mathrm{d}x & = x\sqrt{x^{2} + 1} - \int\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 1}}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = x\sqrt{x^{2} + 1} - \int\sqrt{x^{2} + 1}\mathrm{d}x + \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 1}}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
which implies that
\begin{align*}
\int\sqrt{x^{2} + 1}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\left(x\sqrt{x^{2} + 1} + \text{arcsinh}(x)\right) + C
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!

$\frac {e^{2\sinh^{-1} x} - e^{-2\sinh^{-1} x}}{8}$ looks ugly but it has a nice simplification:
$$\frac {e^{2\sinh^{-1} x} - e^{-2\sinh^{-1} x}}{8} = \frac {x\sqrt {x^2+1}}{2}$$
You might notice that if we took a step back,
$$\frac {e^{2\theta} + e^{-2\theta}}{8} = \frac {(e^{θ}−e^{−θ})(e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta})}{8}$$
And when you reverse the substitution, just directly put $\frac {e^{\theta}-e^{-\theta}}{2}=x$ and $\frac {e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}}{2}=\sqrt {x^2+1}$.
This might have been more obvious if you worked it all the way through with hyperbolic functions:
$$\begin{align}\int \cosh^2 t\mathrm dt&= \int \frac 12 (\cosh 2t + 1)\mathrm dt\\&= \frac {\sinh 2t}{4} + \frac {t}{2} + C\\&=
\frac {\cosh t\sinh t + t}{2} + C(\because \sinh 2t = 2\cosh t\sinh t)\end{align}$$

The hyperbolic functions are implicit in transformation $(2)$. However, what transformation $(2)$ and the other transformations allow is to bring you into the realm of exponential functions (there aren't as many integration formulas here compared to trigonometric functions, so you don't have to memorize as much).

Transformations $(1, 2, 3)$ allow you to convert rational integrals of trigonometric/hyperbolic functions into integrals of rational functions immediately. Then you can apply partial fraction decomposition. I reiterate, the common complaint from students is that they need to memorize too much for trigonometric/hyperbolic substitutions or rely on tables. The transformations I provide avoid that. The notion of an ugly closed form is subjective.

I don’t think there is any approach simpler than IBP(as answered by Átila), trigonometric and hyperbolic substitutions. I’ll share another way to proceed after performing the hyperbolic substitution $x=\sinh t$(which I think is pretty fast):
$$\begin{align}\int\sqrt{x^2+1}\mathrm dx&=\int(x^2+1)\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\\&=\int\cosh^2t\mathrm dt\\&=\frac12\int1+\cosh2t\mathrm dt\\&=\frac{t}2+\frac{\sinh t\cosh t}2+C\\&=\frac{\sinh^{-1}(x)+x\sqrt{x^2+1}}2+C\end{align}$$

This is better than the trigonometric sub $x=\tan\theta.$. +1

The solution I provide above using exponentials is essentially a hyperbolic substitution. However, I prefer using exponentials because, compared to trigonometric and hyperbolic functions, the derivatives and integrals of exponential functions are simpler. Additionally, it doesn't require memorizing as many identities. I encourage you to take a look at this new technique, of which the general transformations I presented in my original question are just an addition for completeness.

@EmmanuelJoséGarcía I think back-substitution is much simpler in this way, and for understanding this approach, you only need to remember $2$ identities: $$\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1$$ and $$1+\cosh2t=2\cosh^2t$$ which I don’t think are difficult to memorise as they are analogous to the corresponding trigonometric identities.

I'm speaking in general. In an integral competition like the MIT Integration Bee, you would need to memorize many standard formulas for derivatives and integrals to effectively and fluently apply trigonometric or hyperbolic substitution. Exponential substitution significantly reduces the need for memorization.

@BobDobbs thanks for the feedback!

I don’t think this is the fastest method, but I still thought of sharing an alternative perspective. The integrand can be rewritten as $x^0(x^2+1)^\frac12$ which is of the form of Chebyshev’s differential binomial. Hence, substituting $t=\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}$,
$$\mathrm dx=-x^3t\mathrm dt, \sqrt{x^2+1}=xt\text{sgn}x$$
$$\begin{align}\implies \int\sqrt{x^2+1}\mathrm dx&=-\text{sgn}x\int t^2x^4\mathrm dt\\&= -\text{sgn}x\int\frac{t^2}{t^4-2t^2+1}\mathrm dt\end{align}$$
This can now be finished by writing $t^2=\frac12(t^2+1)+\frac12(t^2-1)$.
